# Python regex, find all matches with pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to work with Slack's API and it sends a character string for user names, for instance: <@UCH65RHRC>

Therefore, in the API JSON body's text, there could be several of the above patterns in a line, such as:

"Hi <@UCH65RHRC> and <@UCH65RHRF>, thanks for all the great work!"

How can I use Python's regex to find all the matching strings with this predefined pattern, which is: <@#########>, where the # (9 total) can be 0-9 and A-Z?

Comment: have you tried any regex's that have failed? why didn't they work? show us what you've tried and you'll be much more likely to get helpful responses.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very straightforward task. The regular expression `<@([0-9A-Z]{9})>` should meet your requirement. For example:

```
import re

body = "Hi <@UCH65RHRC> and <@UCH65RHRF>, thanks for all the great work!"
id_search = re.findall("<@([0-9A-Z]{9})>", body)

for id in id_search:
    print(id)
```

This will provide the following output:

```
UCH65RHRC
UCH65RHRF
```